# Entity Framework Model Distinct Function

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, distinct

I am working in Entity Framework Model and i am writing an expression like this:

`medication = objectContext.vClientMedication.Distinct().ToList();`
What should I write in `Distinct` function to get the unique `BrandName`. `BrandName` is an attribute of vClientMedication.

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Linq Distinct on a particular Property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/489258/linq-distinct-on-a-particular-property)

Answer (score 2):

```
medication = objectContext.vClientMedication.Select(o => o.BrandName).Distinct().ToList();
```

Comment: this only returns the name of the brand not object itself.

Comment: maniacneron is right. String is being returned using ur method.

Answer (score 1):

you can use IComparer

```
 public class CustomEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<vClientMedication>
{
    #region IEqualityComparer Members

    public bool Equals(vClientMedication x, vClientMedication y)
    {
        if ((x.BrandName == y.BrandName))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }}
```

then write your query

```
medication = objectContext.vClientMedication.Distinct(new
CustomEqualityComparer()).ToList();
```

Comment: Please see the updated question. I added an image of error getting after using ur code.

Comment: Here is another error `'Pc.PrecisionCare2.DAL.Consumer.Medication.ConsumerMedicationDAO.CustomEqualityComparer' does not implement interface member 'System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer<Pc.PrecisionCare2.ModelTypes.vClientMedication>.GetHashCode(Pc.PrecisionCare2.ModelTypes.vClientMedication)'`

Comment: public int GetHashCode(vClientMedication obj)
        {
            return base.GetHashCode();
        } add this function to your CustomEqualityComparer class